# Why does "Fail" gets printed when I input 7 , 8 and 9?

Tags: python

```
n=input("Guess")
i=1;
if int(n)==9:
   print("You win")
else:
        while int(n)!=9 and i<3:
           n=input("Guess")
           i+=1
        if int(n)==9:
           print("you win")    

if i==3 and n!=9:
  print("Fail")
```

First I input 7  , then 8 and in the end  9 (so 'n' becomes 9) But still, Fail gets printed!

The command below should not run since 'n' is equal to 9

```
if i==3 and n!=9:
  print("Fail")
```

Comment: you forgot to convert the `n` to an int in that conditional `n!=9` (instead of `int(n)!=9`). This is why it might be better to have `n = int(n)` or `n=int(input("Guess"))` rather than casting to an int only while checking.

Comment: You need to convert all `n` to ints while checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you need in a cleaner approach. You should check if the input is really an int, which is not included here:

```
i = 0
while i < 3:
    n = int(input("Guess"))
    i += 1
    if n == 9:
        break

if n == 9:
    print("you win") 
else:
    print("Fail")
```